# How to make graphic with python, Tkinter or not, not inside the rectangular window?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, windows-desktop-gadgets

For example like those gadget where is a figure walking around the screen, or any graphics not bounded inside rectangular window, and even is interactive ?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to do a transparent window and hide the title bar
both are feasible with most graphic library but will be rarely cross platform

I will advise you to look at [this question](https://docs.wxpython.org/index.html) to hide the title bar with tkinter

Tkinter doesn't support transparency so you may need to use [wxPython](https://docs.wxpython.org/index.html) instead

Comment: mm ok, is it possible to do also mouse reaction, like applying mouse action only if cursor is above non-rechtangle object, else apply it to background?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by the background in this case? The implementation of even is purely OS dependent but with a click event you can receive coordinate. From there you can manually map it to certain part of your software. Most graphic library will do it for  you

Comment: OP refers to the gif cat versions where a paw tries to catch the mousecursor while sitting still... or something like it... you get the picture ;p